# python: How to constantly update buttons inside QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a project on PyQT5 and I need to change amount of buttons inside QGirdLayout

I am using PyQT5 to make GUI for my application.
I ask server for amount of buttons that i should display, and server sends me packet with filenames that shoudl be displayed in QGridLayout.
But every time I try to update content of my QGridLayout it does nothing

```
 def DownloadFile(self, LoginHash, PassHash, Filename):
        print("FILE : "+ str(Filename))
    def DisplayFiles(self, data):
        print("Displaying files")
        print(data)
        data = data.split("|")[:len(data.split("|")) - 1]
        buttons = {}
        j, index, prev = 0, 0, 0
        for i in range(0, len(data)):

            if i % 3 == 0:
                j += 1
                index = 0
            index += 1
            buttons[(index, j)] = QPushButton(str(data[prev]))
            prev += 1
            pixmap = QPixmap("./button.png")

            # scriptDir = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))
            # self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(scriptDir + path.sep + 'button.png'))

            print("SYS : + " + (data[prev - 1])[len(str(data[prev - 1])) - len(".mp3"):])
            if ((data[prev - 1])[len(str(data[prev - 1])) - len(".mp3"):] == ".mp3"):
                buttons[(index, j)].setIcon(QIcon('MP3icon.jpg'))
            elif ((data[prev - 1])[len(str(data[prev - 1])) - len(".png"):] == ".png"):
                buttons[(index, j)].setIcon(QIcon('PNGicon.png'))
            elif ((data[prev - 1])[len(str(data[prev - 1])) - len(".html"):] == ".html"):
                buttons[(index, j)].setIcon(QIcon('HTMLicon.jpg'))
                # buttons[(index, j)].setIconSize()
            buttons[(index, j)].clicked.connect(
                partial(DownloadFile, str(window.LoginHash), str(window.PassHash), str(data[prev - 1])))
            buttons[(index, j)].setSizePolicy(
                QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                QSizePolicy.Preferred)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(buttons[(index, j)], index, j)
```

I expect app to change content of Layout but it just doesn't affect it at all

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Excuse me, but what do you mean by that? I have provided all code I have

Comment: An example that I can copy, run and see your problem.

Comment: edited, now you can copy it and run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to understand what exactly you want, here is how i would do it when i understood correctly.
Write a function that removes the old QPushButtons from the grid that follows a similar logic.

```
def delete_old_position(buttons):
    for button in reversed(range(self.gridLayout.count())):
        button_to_remove = self.gridLayout.itemAt(button).widget()
        self.gridLayout.removeWidget(button_to_remove)
        button_to_remove.setParent(None)
```

After that you should be able to fill your grid again with your newly created QPushButtons.

Comment: But how could I delete buttons within the function.
A new buttons array is being initialaised at function start, but how could i delete the old one?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do might look something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from functools import partial
from random import randint

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Get new data", clicked=self.newData), 0, 1)

        data = self.createDate()
        self.DisplayFiles(data)

    def DownloadFile(self, LoginHash, PassHash, Filename):
        print("FILE : "+ str(Filename))

    def DisplayFiles(self, data):
        print("Displaying files")
        data = data.split("|")[:len(data.split("|"))] # - 1]
        buttons = {}
        j, index, prev = 0, 0, 0
        for i in range(0, len(data)):
            if i % 3 == 0:
                j += 1
                index = 0
            index += 1
            buttons[(index, j)] = QPushButton(str(data[prev]))
            prev += 1
            pixmap = QPixmap("Ok.png")

            # scriptDir = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))
            # self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(scriptDir + path.sep + 'button.png'))

#            print("SYS : + " + (data[prev - 1])[len(str(data[prev - 1])) - len(".mp3"):])

            if ((data[prev - 1])[len(str(data[prev - 1])) - len(".mp3"):] == ".mp3"):
                buttons[(index, j)].setIcon(QIcon('MP3icon.jpg'))
            elif ((data[prev - 1])[len(str(data[prev - 1])) - len(".png"):] == ".png"):
                buttons[(index, j)].setIcon(QIcon('PNGicon.png'))
            elif ((data[prev - 1])[len(str(data[prev - 1])) - len(".html"):] == ".html"):
                buttons[(index, j)].setIcon(QIcon('HTMLicon.jpg'))
                # buttons[(index, j)].setIconSize()

            buttons[(index, j)].clicked.connect(
#                partial(DownloadFile, str(window.LoginHash), str(window.PassHash), str(data[prev - 1])))
                partial(self.DownloadFile, str("window.LoginHash"), 
                                           str("window.PassHash"), 
                                           str(data[prev - 1])))

            buttons[(index, j)].setSizePolicy(
                                                QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                                                QSizePolicy.Preferred)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(buttons[(index, j)], index, j)

    def createDate(self): 
        numberOfButtons = randint(2, 11)
        data = '|'.join([ "fileName{}.png".format(i) for i in range(1, numberOfButtons) ])
        return data

    def newData(self):
        countLayout = self.layout().count()
        if countLayout > 1:
            for it in range(countLayout - 1):  
                w = self.layout().itemAt(1).widget()
                self.layout().removeWidget(w)     
                w.hide()
        data = self.createDate()
        self.DisplayFiles(data)   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()  
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]